# 10-bit number in .net

Tags: c#-4.0

I would like to represent a 10 bit unsigned integer in C#. I need to read and write it into `BinaryStream` and use ++ unary operator. Should I use `int` as an internal representation or is there a better way?

Comment: You can't hammer ten bits in a stream, streams are byte based.  Multiples of 8.  You'll need to find the expected format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `unsigned short` as my base type. Writing to binary stream is going to be fun no matter what, because you'll need to pack four of these numbers to get a whole number of bytes into the stream (assuming that you want packing).

Comment: `BinaryWriter` has a `Write(bool value)` method. I can write an extension method for reading a writing so it should not be a problem.

Comment: @vasek7 Writing a `bool` takes up an entire byte, so writing a 10-bit number as ten booleans is too wasteful.

Comment: Is there any possibility to read/write to the file bit by bit?

Comment: @vasek7 Not without writing your own "bit packing" layer: all file systems that I know are byte-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, using an UInt16 caped to 10 bit is a good solution. You will need to overload some operators but that should be it.

The other alternative would be to use a BitArray and to redifine the ++ unary operator.

Comment: I need easy writing/reading to/from `BinaryStream`. It means I need as easy serialization as possible.

Comment: BitArray is serializable, int16 is obviously serializable, although using int16 there is a little overhead of 6 bits by value, which is huge (60%), but can be minimized using packing and padding (group 3 values and pad with 2 '0'), this can be done easily using an int as a container.