# Is there a 10-bits unsigned integer data type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, types, integer, bit

I need to work with unsigned 10 bit integer in C#. I need to represent this so I can do operations on it, such as add and subtract. How do I represent this type since there is no built in one in C#.

I have searched the web, but could not find an answer, but one, that was so blur and not clear.

[10-bit number in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825964/10-bit-number-in-net)

Comment: If no one has created such a class or struct yet, you can create one and feel free to post here as an answer, and also for example on a github repo or gist. As explained in the mentioned link, you can use a embedded ushort which you will wrap with some operators to ensure uncommon 10-bits functionalities and calculation. [A Tutorial on Data Representation](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/datarepresentation.html) | [Bits, Bytes, and Integers](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-s12/www/lectures/02-03-bits-ints-1up.pdf)

Comment: Use any larger integer type (like `ushort`, which is 16 bits) and mask off the upper bits on every operation. Mathematically, a "10 bit unsigned integer" is just a value that is always calculated modulo 1024.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can you give an example, and one more question. The 10 bit number is at most 1024, so what if the user entered a number more than that ?

Comment: [How to create 24 bit unsigned integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010178/how-to-create-24-bit-unsigned-integer-in-c)

Comment: Can you explain why to need to work with 10-bit numbers and what you want to do with them? As in: why not just use a 16-bit short?

Comment: What if? That's up to you. Reporting an error or reducing the number modulo 1024 would be the obvious choices. Whether `1 + 1023` is an overflow error or just `0` is up to you.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing needs to implement in C#, a calculator that uses unsigned 10 bits integer.

Comment: Ah, an assignment. That explains the need for an uncommon bit length: you will need to think about limits (like what to do on 1023+1) yourself instead of relying on built in functionality. Can values in your calculator require more than one "dectet"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define "custom" integer-based type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615113/define-custom-integer-based-type)